# падеж неопределенных количественых числительных

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, числительные

Правильна ли  падежная  форма  неопределенного  количественного  числительного в  вопросительном  предложении  "Сколько не хватает  карандашей?" и  не  должно ли быть  "Скольких  не хватает  карандашей?", если в  ответ следует: "Не хватает пяти карандашей"?